# Typo3 CKEditor image from FAL

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typoscript, tsconfig, fal

I set up a fresh TYPO3 8.7.4 installation with CKEditor and `rte_ckeditor_image` to get images from FAL.

In the documentation from `rte_ckeditor_image` it says:

> The maximum dimensions relate to the configuration for magic images
>   which have to be set in Page TSConfig:
>
> ```
> # Page TSConfig
> RTE.default.buttons.image.options.magic {
>     maxWidth = 1020  # Default: 300
>     maxHeight = 800  # Default: 1000
> }
> ```

I did this, but still I can't make the width of an image bigger than 300px.

I looked at the source code from TYPO3 already.
There is a file `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/Service/MagicImageService.php`which got two variables: `$magicImageMaximumWidth` and `$magicImageMaximumHeight`. If change the value of them, I can make the width of an image bigger then 300px.

The file got also a function `setMagicImageMaximumDimensions(array $rteConfiguration)` which should change thoose two variables but seems like it doesn't do so.

Did I do something wrong or is it impossible to change the maximumg image dimensions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have an linebreak after `# Page TSConfig`?

Comment: Yes, there is one. I'll update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please remove the comments after maxWidth and maxHeight (`# Default: xxx`) and try again? I looked at the source of `rte_ckeditor_image` and there the function `setMagicImageMaximumDimensions` seams to be used correctly. Did you see the limitation in setting the size larger or at rendering the magic image?

Comment: This works! Thank you dude, i don't know why I doesn't tried this by myself. Could you post this as answer so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the comments after maxWidth and maxHeight (`# Default: xxx`) and try again.

Comments in TYPO3 are only allowed as new row not inline.